# different types of #include in C++

Tags: c++, include

//To all those marking this as a duplicate, I did search before and found some similar ones, however, those did not fully answer my question and I'm still not sure how to answer the question I have included in this post. I need someone nice enough to explain their difference a little bit more in depth.

What is the difference of #include < something > and #include "something.h" ? 
Also can someone tell me why the 3rd option is right in the multiple choice question below?

Suppose you wanted to make use of terminal control routines I gave and all your codes are put in
yourprog.cpp. The interface for terminal control is declared in term control.h and the
implementation is stored in term control.cpp. Which of the following include lines should
be put in yourprog.cpp so your program can use the terminal control routines?

1. `include <term control>`
2. `include <term control.h>`
3. `include "term control.h"`
4. `include <iostream>`

Comment: Well the whole point of include is to include a reference to a file containing code, which is why this file must be mentioned. Did you mean to type just the word include for choices 1,2 and 4?

Comment: "" tells to compiler to look in the local directory, and usually the predefined header directories as well

Comment: @PaulG No I had the rest in tags and they didn't appear so I had to make some changes and now it works. I'd much appreciate if you could clarify the question also

Comment: @RahulTripathi how about the tags?

Comment: @GelaMp:- <> tells the compiler to look in predefined header directories only

Comment: Can someone post a link to the alleged duplicate?